# How to convert Object to Dictionary in JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, json, json.net

how do I convert a JObject to Dictioary?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since [`JObject` implements `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm), you could just create a `new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>()` passing that object into the constructor.

Comment: I dont even need to convert it then, but thanks, your answer has brought me the right way.

Comment: Finn, can you post your solution?

Comment: @David Nelson: Unlikely - he hasn't been seen since end of 2011.